# arguments to callback not being passed (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

In the code below, I am trying to pass the argument "test" to the callback. The good news is that the callback is indeed being called; however, the string "I see undefined" is being printed instead of "I see test".

```
var MyObject = function(){
}

MyObject.prototype.b = function(data){
   console.log("I see " + data);
}

a = function(callback){
   callback("test");
}

var it = new MyObject();
a(function(){it.b()});
```

I have a hunch it has something to do with the closure, since I see the string "I see test" printed if I call it.b("test") directly. Why isn't the function receiving the argument properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `it.b()` with no arguments, so it should be no surprise that there are no arguments when you get in the `b()` method.  If you want an argument to appear for `it.b()`, you have to declare it in your callback so you can then pass it to `it.b(arg)`.

```
a(function(arg){
    it.b(arg)
});
```

Or, you could pass all arguments from the callback:

```
a(function(){
    it.b.apply(it, arguments)
});
```

Or, you could use `.bind()`.

```
a(it.b.bind(it));
```

Comment: Ah, I see ... I knew a(it.b) wouldn't work, so I blindly put the function stuff around it since I saw that on another site. I thought that just was a special syntax, but now it's clear that it's actually creating a new unnamed function. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are creating a new anonymous function that you are passing as the callback to a. If you change that last line to:

```
a(it.b);
```

Everything should work as you're expecting.

Comment: This will get the arguments, but then `this` will not be the `it` object inside of the `b` method.

Comment: Sure, and if he needs `this` to be the `it` object, he should bind it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Lets analyse the last line of your code:

```
a(function(){it.b()});

//I will name the above function 'xyz' for convenience
a(function xyz(){it.b()});
```

In the above line you are passing a function xyz as an arguement to a(). The function you are passing directly calls it.b() without passing it any paramter.

So what happens here is that when you pass xyz to a(), xyz is called with string "test" as a parameter i.e xyz("test") is called. But this string "test" is not of any use as you are directly calling it.b() without passing it any data and hence you get 'undefined'.

To get the output you desire you need to write the code by any of the following two methods.

Method 1:

```
var MyObject = function(){
}

MyObject.prototype.b = function(data){
   console.log("I see " + data);
}

a = function(callback){
   callback("test");
}

var it = new MyObject();
a(it.b);
```

Method 2:

```
var MyObject = function(){
}

MyObject.prototype.b = function(data){
   console.log("I see " + data);
}

a = function(callback){
   callback("test");
}

var it = new MyObject();
a(function(data){it.b(data)});
```